How to use wp-cli's post list function to return posts published in a specific date range?
I'm trying to use wp-cli's wp post list function to select posts from a specific date range but I cannot figure out the proper syntax to use.
According to its documentation, you can use the syntax from WP_QUERY class, so it looks to be possible.
Specifically, I'm trying to list all posts that were published between a date range of 2020-06-01 and 2018-03-01
I found that wp-cli has a year parameter that's mostly undocumented so wp post list --year=2020 does return all posts published in 2020 but I need to be able to filter by a specific month and day as well.

how do you want to use the result of this command ? have think about using the api that can return a lots of information and allows to be customised if necessary : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

@mmm - I'm using output as a part of a bash script to migrate and batch update content (adjusting categories, reassigning authors, replacing urls within post content, etc.).  I need the date filter tobe just one parameter of a larger command "wp post list --author=42 --post_type=special_name --format=ids"

Seems like it's currently not possible, short of writing your own WP CLI command, thought you're not the only one, and there is active conversation about it. https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3039 https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/4616
